# Trying to convert text inside a text_area to HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a sort of blog in Rails, and when I put something like

```
Hello, <b> how are you? </b>
```

inside the text_area and I send it, I see that it was saved as a plain text, and the HTML inside it is not recognized.
The only thing I want is that every single HTML tag that I put in the text_area be interpreted as HTML and not as a plain text.

For example, the first code should be shown in my page like this:

> Hello,  **how are you?**

This is the code of the post's view *new* (in HAML):

```
= form_for @post do |f|
    .form
        .flabel= f.label :title
        = f.text_field :title
        .flabel= f.label :content
        = f.text_area :content
        .submit= f.submit "Create"
```

How could I do this without [HTMLArea](http://www.htmlarea.com/) or things like that?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `raw` helper? Try the folliwing `<%= raw @post.content %>` in your view.

Comment: Thank you! All I had to do is to put the raw method just as you said!

Answer (score 1):

I think `<%= @post.content.html_safe %>` would also work.